# Jw player videos are not playing on after facebook timeline post

Tags: php, facebook, video, jwplayer

I have an issue playing embedded video on Facebook. I'm using the *jwplayer* player to post video on Facebook using an iframe (like youtube).  In my embed file I use the properties below:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Neighbors title " />
<meta property="og:description" content="A couple with a house." />
<meta property="og:image" content="video Image file path added here" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf?file=xyz.mp4&autostart=true" />
```

But this is not working.  Is there any Facebook account setting required to play the video? Every time I search on Google it redirects me to share stories and canvas URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JW5 for this - http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/

Also FB embedding requires HTTPs now.

Comment: Is it still possible to download JWPlayer 5 somewhere? I only see version 6 on the website. Or is it now impossible for someone new to JWPlayer to get a working player that supports facebook embedding?

Comment: Licensed version is available here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/order/view, free version is available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.10

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer , when do you think this serious missing feature will be covered? We -as an ads version customer of JW6- can not make our videos play in Facebook. Maybe you'd better put an explanation to http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/

Comment: I'm not sure of the eta, but the main reason this was removed because embedding in the method player.swf?file=blahblah opens up a huge security vulnerability and has many XSS issues (cross site scripting). It was removed because we didn't want this security hole in the new product. If you are a JW6 customer, we can send you the JW5 licensed player, just email us - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/, you can always run the JW5 player in the OG tags on the site, while using JW6 to embed videos at the same time. We are currently doing that for all JW Platform embeds (formerly Bits on the Run).

Comment: What I posted above is still the case.

Comment: JWP 6 will support this feature?

Comment: It will not support this.